InfluxDB + Grafana: Status codes by time
I am trying to display HTTP status codes in Grafana by time.
The data is stored in InfluxDB like this (simplified):
# time,status,bytesize
2024-04-27 11:24:00, 404,100
2024-04-28 01:24:00, 200,100
...

Currently I am using the SQL for querying:
SELECT $__dateBin(time) AS time,
COUNT(CASE WHEN "status" BETWEEN 200 AND 299 THEN 1 END) AS "2xx",
COUNT(CASE WHEN "status" BETWEEN 400 AND 499 THEN 1 END) AS "4xx",
COUNT(CASE WHEN "status" >= 500 THEN 1 END) AS "5xx"
FROM http_requests
GROUP BY $__dateBin(time)

This produces the following graph:

As you can see the values are displayed correctly but points are directly connected and the Graph doesn't go back to the baseline (0).
How can I fix this?

In Grafana, there is an option to Connect null values. Furthermore, perhaps there should be a fill(None) or something similar to set it back to "the baseline".

I was able to achieve empty rows by utilising InfluxDB's date_bin_gapfill function. It can be used with the $__interval variable from Grafana:
SELECT
  date_bin_gapfill($__interval, time) as _time,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN "status" BETWEEN 200 AND 299 THEN 1 END) AS "2xx",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN "status" BETWEEN 400 AND 499 THEN 1 END) AS "4xx",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN "status" >= 500 THEN 1 END) AS "5xx"
FROM "http_requests"
WHERE
    time >= $__timeFrom
    AND time <= $__timeTo
GROUP BY _time, status
ORDER BY _time

Then I had to select the option to interpolate missing values with 0:

And this made the graph look as expected.
